# Get the list of commits with specific branch (egit-github lib)

Tags: github, egit, github-api

I use egit-github library to load all commits from GitHub, now I need to list all commits from a specific branch other than master, how I can do with this library

Answer (score 1):

The basic example to list *all* commits is in [`api/LogCommandTest.java#L83`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommandTest.java#L83)

```
Iterator<RevCommit> log = git.log().all().call().iterator();
```

You can Mark a commit to start graph traversal from `LogCommand add(AnyObjectId start)` : [`LogCommand.java#L163-L191`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.java#L163-L191)

You can get the ref of a branch with `Ref Repository.getRef(final String name)` [`lib/Repository.java#L901-L914`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/d84661003526167ad474c264a87360d567defda9/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.java#L901-L914), as used in [`pgm/StatusTest.java#L326`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/d84661003526167ad474c264a87360d567defda9/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/StatusTest.java#L326):

```
 String commitId = db.getRef(Constants.MASTER).getObjectId().name();
```

([`MASTER` is simply "`master`"](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/d84661003526167ad474c264a87360d567defda9/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Constants.java#L233))

Passing `db.getRef("yourBranchName").getObjectId()` to a `LogCommand.add()` should allow you to list all commits reachable from that branch.